# Why isn't one of my values moving into my async block?

Tags: rust, move

I have a macro that looks like this

```rust
use reqwest::Client;

struct Source {
    url: String,
    version: RefCell<String>,
}

let client = Client::new();
let client_ref = &client;

let request = |url| async move {
    client_ref
        .get(url)
        .send()
        .await
        .expect("couldn't send request")
        .error_for_status()
        .expect("http error")
};

let mut site_update = false;
macro_rules! api_page {
    ( $source:expr ) => {{
        let response = request($source.url.as_str()).await;
        let ver = response
            .headers()
            .get("Last-Modified")
            .unwrap()
            .to_str()
            .unwrap();
        let mut old = $source.version.borrow_mut();

        if ver != old.as_str() {
            site_update = true;
        }

        || async move {
            *old = ver.into();
        }
    }};
}

let result = api_page!(Source {
    url: "http://example.org"
    version: "".into()
});
```

unfortunately, I get errors saying `response does not live long enough` and `ver does not live long enough`, since they get dropped at the end of the macro block.

this problem only happens when I try to use `ver` inside the closure, but using `response` and `old` works as expected. my only guess is that `ver` isn't getting moved into the async block properly, but I'm not sure why.

if this has something to do with the methods I'm calling on response, [the response object I'm using can be found here](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/struct.Response.html). thanks.

Comment: `ver` is probably a `&str` referencing `response`, moving a reference doesn't unbind it

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include the errors *as text* (instead of an image).

Comment: sorry about that, kind of rushed this one. and you're right about the reference, this solved my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ver` was referencing `response` which still refers to the old value after moving it

Comment: guess I need to wait two days?